# How do you define a function that takes a union member and returns the next member of that union?

Tags: typescript

[This snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEFkG8AmwDOCUwAtqHGAPZQBcyA5HPQL4CwAUKJLIiqgELY8hYmRAVqdegCMWHLtHhI0AYSEEipclVoMEc9hzABPAA4oA8lBzQIOVOEW9kAXmzJqN3SACuJadAA3MgKPEh0GMgAPmiCMahqzIEcRmaW1rb2jmEQ+K4cyNHuntB0AAzBoUoQEZhs7IUxWB4ZugCMldnVEYL1jcWtdABMndzdqshJKewwPiAIYMCUIMgA5hBgAHIQAB5gDmO8-IgA1gA8BcjH+Ci7kCA4eVZedgdOSAA0l9t7yHcQDyerVeXV4HAAfAAKaRwG5vHJ0a4QADa9CqvHoAF0AJR0H5gVHopBY7CXKAbHxQFZYZjIWF0kDGZLseocAD0bLQeTAAAtbIU4MgAO5wYzIKhrDbivk3ZAc5AISgkEgAsDcygKpWmYAAGwgAH52ZzFSB8GAQtJXJKtnd4dVjggTpDcBpRNpJAwmMxsch8BQCDBgLlYsy2QAqZAAUSgUEkHAAKmkGJF4nFVPRkDhKMGQJRzX7FvgYGLebcduYFnZxUn6AJ6AA6S6J8zJ9AZgjIXPm2H4YCrcTSPXijUmFu1-gNy6FZvBygwZCmWPmKAmBjCTRiCRQDNwckheZa-2DiCNhqFc8zhgAIjgV-beS7dPwvf7cGPw+rY6v0jvp7DbOmeUTTNEIECtdYbT2O0jlOZ11zdcQdCkWRvV9f0iyDPIElDY1lhA6BYygcCNnxaCkAdJ0XRELREI9eh9FQgsA0wzsIAANyCIA) shows what I'm trying to achieve and where I'm stuck:

```
interface IA {discriminator: 'a'}
interface IB {discriminator: 'b'}
interface IC {discriminator: 'c'}

type OrderedInterface = { order: number; interface: IA | IB | IC };

type OrderedInterfaces =
  | { order: 0; interface: IA }
  | { order: 1; interface: IB }
  | { order: 2; interface: IC };

function getNextInterfaceBack<
  Base extends OrderedInterface,
  Next extends OrderedInterface
>(baseInterface: Base['interface']): Next['interface'] {
  return {} as any;
}

// Is there  a way to get these // comments to compile?
// const ib = getNextInterfaceBack({discriminator: 'a'}) satisfies IB;
/* Error:
Type 'IA | IB | IC' does not satisfy the expected type 'IB'.
  Type 'IA' is not assignable to type 'IB'.
    Types of property 'discriminator' are incompatible.
      Type '"a"' is not assignable to type '"b"'.
*/

// const ic = getNextInterfaceBack({discriminator: 'b'}) satisfies IC;
// const error = getNextInterfaceBack({discriminator: 'c'}) satisfies never;
```

Basically, I want to know if it's possible to write a type safe implementation of that `getNextInterfaceBack` function.

I feel like I'm getting close in [this attempt](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEFkG8CwAoZZAE2AGcEpgBbUOMAeygC5kByOVgbnwF99RIsRClQAhbPkIlylGiDqMWrAEZde-cNHhI0AYQkFiZCtVoNmbBGrx88+MAE8ADigBqcADbAiouKQjoIEQAchAAHmComkI6ALySyAA+2MjKfhAsGJzIIOFgmeK2hMlYqekF2bkRmfo83HZ4MACuIAhgwPQgyADmEGChEVGC2hC+CADWADzieRBBpMjuXj7pgSF5Q1rCAHwAFAlp-psxGciiANoq6awAuvgAlCwXrFVgtwaEUH1NUF1YPMg-ICQA56rZ8AB6CFoBZgAAW0BQgOQAHc4A5kAwen1MQj-MgocgEPQqFQ5mBYfQiSSnMAPBAAPyQ6HEkCkMDIYDKZCxbH9DbREZjca7UrSExyBQWdisZA8e7IUh0MgwYAQBZieoQgBUyAAolAoIp8AAVZwoVgYJJocTJVC6WVEejqnL0DlK9qkGAY+EocIuNoQIiY81sMSsAB0CTNLjD6FlZFdHL8pGA3XkynpmKpjljltEkYShBjLvoMGQTiNLigjjY4tkZkYsrgX05rRpyszECjhkIxdDrAARHBBwmFiA3YDSKn03Au9mQ3nB8pRz3tRD8MzqWyOcAEDy+QNIoLhMLRUYZKZ5OYlKo5QqPSq1RrdFrob1+YMT0gz2LjA3r0USxZXlbJCWgI0oFIABCfAgA).

```
interface IA {
  discriminator: 'a';
}
interface IB {
  discriminator: 'b';
}
interface IC {
  discriminator: 'c';
}

type ValidBaseAndNextInterface =
  | { base: IA; next: IB }
  | { base: IB; next: IC };

function getNextInterfaceBack<B extends ValidBaseAndNextInterface>(
  baseInterface: B['base']
): B['next'] {
  return {} as any;
}

// Is there  a way to get these // comments to compile?
// const ib = getNextInterfaceBack({ discriminator: 'a' }) satisfies IB;
/* Error:
Type 'IA | IB | IC' does not satisfy the expected type 'IB'.
  Type 'IA' is not assignable to type 'IB'.
    Types of property 'discriminator' are incompatible.
      Type '"a"' is not assignable to type '"b"'.
*/

// const ic = getNextInterfaceBack({ discriminator: 'b' }) satisfies IC;
// getNextInterfaceBack({ discriminator: 'c' }); // errors!
```

I can't figure out how to narrow (is this the right term?) the parameter's interface (`base`) with a single-member of `ValidBaseAndNextInterface` for the return type (`next`); in general I always get stuck here, and this is one of many, many attempts to solve this problem.

Is there a way to get this to compile in a type safe way?

I don't want the *runtime* signature of the `getNextInterfaceBack` function or the interface implementations to be modified, but the rest is fair game.

---

[I found a way to get it to work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEFkG8CwAoZZAE2AGcEpgBbUOMAeygC5kByOVgbnwF99RIsRClQAhbPkIlylGiDqMWrAEZde-cNHhI0AYQkFiZCtVoNmbBGrx88+MAE8ADilFxSEdCCIA5CAA8wVE0hHQBebGRldwgWDGQAHzRxJNRdTmQQALA4zFSUvWQebjs8RxdkADU4ABtgIjcPL19s4MFtFDDJRMjoj1yMrMC48VtCJKwomJHB7Lj9Yvx8GABXEAQwYHoQZABzCDA-QLatYTcEAGsAHnFsiG9SKtr6xs9vI6CQjoA+AApuvoQE6hWLIUQAbRUMVYAF18ABKFgAUUCUEQYCu1TqDRizQ+wI6ABpkOUIPQYFMPAThJDpCY5AooLDvgZCFADisoDssDxkO4+SAHCVbPgAPSitCPMAAC2gKD5yAA7nAHCT6HsDiTZR5kOLkAh6FQqPcwFL1QaqE5gDUIAB+fAGkCkMDIYDKZARfaHVpfM6IC6-SZ02RmRRsDhFeHIUh0MgwYAQR5iEqO52uhAejXe46+pDnANB4wh+TmJSqSPR2OkeOJvQlL343MQfOBowyUwlsOsKyRjJ66BQRikACEQA) but I still don't understand why I had involve `Extract` (see below).

In my previous example, why isn't the type `B` effectively the same as my usage of `Extract`; why isn't `B` "narrowed" to a single member of `ValidBaseAndNextInterface`?

```
interface IA {
  discriminator: 'a';
}
interface IB {
  discriminator: 'b';
}
interface IC {
  discriminator: 'c';
}

type ValidBaseAndNextInterface =
  | { base: IA; next: IB }
  | { base: IB; next: IC };

function getNextInterfaceBack<B extends ValidBaseAndNextInterface>(
  baseInterface: B['base']
): Extract<ValidBaseAndNextInterface, typeof baseInterface['discriminator']> {
  return {} as any;
}

// Is there  a way to get these // comments to compile?
const ib = getNextInterfaceBack({ discriminator: 'a' }) satisfies IB;
const ic = getNextInterfaceBack({ discriminator: 'b' }) satisfies IC;
getNextInterfaceBack({ discriminator: 'c' }); // errors!
```

Comment: If you need them to be ordered, why not use a tuple? https://tsplay.dev/w6peYm

Comment: @pink That's helpful, although I don't understand a lot of the syntax of `Next`. I've never seen something like `O extends unknown[] = OrderedInterfaces` before. Also, how would you implement `getNextInterfaceBack`? I'm guessing you would need a `const orderedInterfacesArray = [IA, IB, IC] as const;` but... I don't think you can do that because those our interfaces, not values. Is the only solution to `switch`/`if/else` on the `discriminator`?

Comment: Have you considered using (abstract) classes so you can "use" the types at runtime? https://tsplay.dev/w8Xgrw I've also added a comment that explains what `Next` is doing, but if you need a step-by-step explanation I can also do that.

Comment: @pink I actually haven't looked into ts `class`es yet so that was illuminating. I think I would prefer to stick to interfaces though. In your comment, you say `function Next(I, O: readonly unknown[] = [])`. Why is it `= []` instead of `= [IA, IB, IC]`? Maybe this question is a good enough reason to do a step-by-step explanation, sorry. BTW, what are the benefits to your solutions compared to mine?

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo, it should be `[IA, IB, IC]`. I'll do a step-by-step explanation in an answer. My solutions "scale" better. As you can see, I only need to edit the `OrderedInterfaces` tuple, which is pretty easy. With yours, I need to manually define more members of the union and add them to `BaseAndNextInterface` as well.

Comment: @pink ha, I also have typos. `BaseAndNextInterface` was unused. I agree with your other points though. Thanks.

Comment: @pink When I renamed `infer Next` to `infer Second`, everything clicked. Very cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `[current, next]` tuples this becomes obvious
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEFkG9kBNgDOCUwAtqHGAPZQBcyA5HA8gL4CwAUKJLIiqgBC2PIWJkK1OowBGLDt3DR4SNAGER%20IiXIhKNegwTyuXMAE8ADigDyUXNAi5USvkgLIAvF2TIAPsgA2hgANGiCALo%20-kFCYahqUZy%20AcFqYSAQAG7QEQDcppwwAK4gCGDAVCDIAOYQYAByEAAeYC68KhCCiADWADzR3QQoLZAguB52DlBO7cr8BIEADBEhXAB8ABQycMNzbhD0QxAAlPQAoq1QiGB9U47Orp0EYYHHYXAg5hHrgQCMEWw0RmYGKUGqWFYyF20K%20BU4Ci4CCqBDAyGAMi8tXqTVa%20063QQPU2OC04l0%20mkTHkJ2QBEohBgwAgHiE8ORIFR6IQWLqjVG%20P4hOJpLEOkkBlkNLpDIITJZ6nZKLR0CgNF5OIFTyFvRJom0Ej0UkMxjYtPpFTlzI8mRyUHhQA)

```
interface IA { discriminator: 'a' }
interface IB { discriminator: 'b' }
interface IC { discriminator: 'c' }

type OrderedInterfaces =
  | [IA, IB]
  | [IB, IC]
  | [IC, never];

// use an overload for generic types. implementation cannot have them.
function getNextInterfaceBack<
  Base extends OrderedInterfaces[0],
>(baseInterface: Base): Extract<OrderedInterfaces, [Base, any]>[1];
function getNextInterfaceBack(baseInterface: OrderedInterfaces[0]): OrderedInterfaces[1] {
  switch (baseInterface.discriminator) {
    case 'a': return { discriminator: 'b' };
    case 'b': return { discriminator: 'c' };
    default: throw new Error(`discriminator "${baseInterface.discriminator}" has no next one`)
  }
}

const ib = getNextInterfaceBack({ discriminator: 'a' }) satisfies IB;
const ic = getNextInterfaceBack({ discriminator: 'b' }) satisfies IC;
const error = getNextInterfaceBack({ discriminator: 'c' }) satisfies never;
```

Comment: Ah, I like that better than my last example. How would you implement that function though?

Comment: @DanielKaplan here's function

Answer (score 1):

Using a tuple instead makes this very easy
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEFkG9kBNgDOCUwAtqHGAPZQBcyA5HA8gL4CwAUKJLIiqgBC2PIWJkK1OowBGLDt3DR4SNAGER+IiXIhKNegwTyuXMAE8ADigDyUXNAi5USvkgLIAvMgDaGADRogoGoagC6ppwW1sgAchAAHmAAPAAyhGDIiZAguB5wIOY+YSGQpAB8XlzIyAA+yOkEmdkQuR4+oDDQyABigZ3dAMqBAHRjA1DI6GHIAPzVdb1ZSa15aGVzyIML9PFJyT7DyGMj06UQFTvIIBAAbtCRMACuIAhgwFQgyADmEGB7YBcvBUEEEiAA1skFmCCCgWm1kHYHFAnEDlPwCD4QE9SDJoCUuOUABQyOCwtFuCD0GEQACUu2yySRjmcrhBBECNMqWAWKLATygXywrGQZNFhQA3FwFFwAPSytAeMAAC0cNTgyAA7nBzMhqD8-nrVbDkPLkAgqKRSK0wEqqObLZZgAAbCDzTgWkBNZDAGReA3-bIUkFghDgok4LTiXT6aRMeS05AESiEGDACAeIRSj2fb3ABD+36BpLB-ih8ORsQ6SQGWQJpMpghpjPqbOe73QKA0Qt-AGlpDliOibQSPRSQzGNiJ5PvJvpjw3e5QCVAA)

```
type OrderedInterfaces = [IA, IB, IC]

type Next<List extends any[], Item> =
  | List extends [infer F, infer S, ...infer A] ?
    | F extends Item ? S
    : Next<[S, ...A], Item>
  : never

function getNextInterfaceBack<
  Base extends OrderedInterfaces[number],
>(baseInterface: Base): Next<OrderedInterfaces, Base> {
  return {} as any;
}
```

Comment: Can you show how to implement that function? Thanks